# How to check if a path is a pip installable package in python 3

Tags: python, pip

I'd like to know if a local path is a pip installable package meaning that I can execute `pip install my_path` with it. Is there an easy way to do that ?

Hence my_path could be a wheel path, a folder with a setup.py file etc.

Answer (score 1):

Checking the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#argument-handling) gives us an idea. `pip install` accepts, among others, a

> Local directory (which must contain a setup.py, or pip will report an error).

So as a minimum, to be able to run `pip install .` the current directory would need to contain a `setup.py` file

Comment: Thanks fo the answer, I'd also need to check for `.whl`, poetry packaged and everything.. I'd like to know if I need to add those format manually or maybe there already is a pip function that I could call. I dug into the code but didn't find anything yet.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. The presence of a whl file in a directory does not mean `pip install .` works in that directory. Where would you need to add formats to manually?

Comment: Sorry I wasn’t super clear, I’ll update the question